# Linux: Specifying top level-directory when creating zip archive

Tags: linux, unix, zip, path, archiving

I have project with the usual directory structure (src/, bin/, ...), i.e

```
project-name/
|-- bin
|-- lib
|-- src
`-- Makefile
```

And would like to create an archive with the following directory structure:

```
project-name-version/
|-- bin
|-- lib
|-- src
`-- Makefile
```

Is there a neat way to do this, which avoids creating a temporary directory `project-name/` elsewhere, then copying the files inside a finally calling `zip -r ...` on that temporary directory?

(I am basically looking for some kind of path prefix or relative path option.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maybe this already occurred to you, but why not just use a sym link rather than copy everything?

```
ln -s project-name project-name-version
```

then use `zip -r` through the sym link (`zip` will dereference sym links by default)? When you're done you can simply `rm` the sym link. Perhaps it's not the most elegant solution, but I don't know an obvious way to do it through `zip` directly.

Comment: This also works with `tar` if you use the `-h` flag.

Comment: (I'm also using the `z` flag; I'm not sure if that affects it.)

Answer (score 17):

This is more an advice than an answer: use [Git](http://git-scm.com/)!

If you setup a [Git](http://git-scm.com/) repository for your project, the whole thing become quite straightforward:

```
git archive HEAD --prefix=project-name-version/ \
    --format=zip -o project-name-version.zip
```

Comment: Excellent advice, thank you. git archive documentation: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive

Comment: While using version control is a good idea, this answer does not match the question for the generic case.

Comment: @Raim "This is more an advice than an answer: use Git!" written there since like 4 years, thank you for pointing it out...

Comment: If this was not intended as an answer, it should be converted to a comment.

Comment: I think that the downside of using `git archive` is that files like .gitignore go into the created archive, as well. Does anybody know a remedy?

Comment: @Gregor I think that's a desirable behavior as such files are actually part of the project, anyway you can use Git attributes, e.g., create a file named `.gitattributes` containing `.git* export-ignore`.

Comment: Thank you, @cYrus, good solution. My goal was to make source code publicly available, in which case you do not want those files included.

Comment: Does this recursively include initialized submodules?