# Create zip-archive with path prefix

Tags: linux

Related to [specifying top level-directory when creating zip archive](https://superuser.com/questions/392569/linux-specifying-top-level-directory-when-creating-zip-archive), is there a simple way to create a zip-archive with a path prefix?

With [tar](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tar), one can use `--transform 's,^,/some/path/,'` but this isn't available with the [zip](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zip) utility.

For example, adding a `nodejs/` prefix to an archive containing `node_modules` in order to create an [AWS Lambda layer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html).

For this specific case, a workaround is:

```bash
$ ln -s . nodejs
$ zip -r layer.zip nodejs/node_modules
```

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1464877/add-prefix-folder-name-to-each-file-inside-of-the-zip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> With tar, one can use `--transform 's,^,/some/path/,'` but this isn't available with the zip utility.

The `bsdtar` tool has a similar `-s` option and supports creating Zip archives:

```
bsdtar -c -a -f foo.zip -s ",^,foo/," *.txt
```

`bsdtar` is part of libarchive, available on most Linux distributions. (Windows 10 also bundles bsdtar as tar.exe but unfortunately without `-s` support.)